# SSIS rounding number to 2

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, derived-column

I have a column of type `DT_NUMERIC(16,4)`. How can I round to number to 2 digits is SSIs in derived column? 
I tried sound(column,2) and it doesnt work for me.

I have also tried `(DT_NUMERIC,16,4)ROUND([Column],2)` , it doesnt work either

Currently I have = `21.7000`
I want = `21.70`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try casting to `(DT_NUMERIC,16,2)`, use the following expression:

```
(DT_NUMERIC,16,2)ROUND([Column],2)
```

Also you can try this:

```
ROUND(((DT_NUMERIC)([Column])), 2)
```

Or

```
(DT_DECIMAL,2)[Column]
```

Comment: Hi Yahfouhi.Thanks for reply but both of them dont work . I really need to get it done..

Comment: @Kate try `(DT_DECIMAL,2)[Column]`

Comment: @kate i am waiting for a reply

Comment: Wait I have to run after I do something on my pkg.

Comment: (DT_NUMERIC,16,2)ROUND([Column],2) works for me... thanks a lot